# mysqli_fetch_array picking only a single value from a SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm learning PHP and MySQL and I have a question.

```
<?php
require('../connect_db.php');

$q='SELECT price FROM towels WHERE color = "Red"';
$r=mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {$var=$row[0];}
```

In  my case, I have towels with different prices that have `color="Red"`. But it seems that the output in `$var` is only one of those prices.

It doesn't even seem to be always the largest or smallest price, or the price belonging to the first PrimaryKey in my table, or anything else that would seem intuitive.

so what is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing, woops, i was gonna post another question first

Comment: Please go through the community before posting duplicate questions. This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924387/mysqli-query-only-returning-first-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ordering you need to add following to the end:

```
ORDER BY price ASC
```

You are iterating throught your results in while. So every iteration `$var` gets the price of the next element. Depending on what you want to do with the prices you can list all of them in a seperate array. But as you didnt discribe what you want to do I can't exactly help you with that. If you edit that i can continue further on helping

Comment: Thanks. Ordering, yes, that is clear. When I echo $var after my "while" loop, I always get one specific price. How can I actually output all the prices that match my SELECT query?

Comment: echo the $var inside the while